# Is it possible to port forward and host a server and then having your friends join without giving away your public ip?

Tags: port-forwarding

I'm a novice when it comes to networking. Is it possible for me to port forward, host a server, and then give out something that isn't my public ip but still redirects to the server? An example would be like let's say a minecraft server. I open the port 25565. I create a server. Can I share something to my friends that will redirect them to my server without sharing my public ip address? Like a proxy or something?

Comment: I suppose you could use a dynamic dns address, but it's trivial, to do a ping on that address.  Why exactly are you hesitant to provide your public ip address?  Even if you were to use a proxy, your public ip address, it would still be trivial to determine your public ip address.

Comment: There is 1 person in my group of friends that I'm not too good on terms with. I'm a bit scared they're gonna dos me haha.

Comment: They could "DOS" you regardless if they know the dynamic DNS address or proxy address.  A single user cannot "DOS" a sever.  It sounds like you are worried about something that is an extremely unlikely event.  You could just NOT allow the friend access to your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is like asking your friends over but not divulging your address.
It's impossible, really.

However, if you don't have a static IP address, then just turning off your router
for some (relatively long) time may get you a new and different IP address.

I suggest to contact the Support of your ISP and ask them about how they assign
the IP address for a router that was turned on. If they allocate addresses
randomly, then this is a solution.

Comment: Mr @harrymc is correct here but there is no guarantee that they won't simply give you back the same address you just had. :^P

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: True, but the chance for that is very low.

Comment: I've only had two IP addresses in nearly 20 years. The one change happened when they 'imported' a new address range, otherwise I'd still be on the same one. This has remained through power-cuts, accidental cutting of a main cable several miles away resulting in 2 weeks' downtime… so it really depends on the ISP.